# Replace the attribute value using cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

The following code is used to replace all the `<img>` tags `src` value. But the following code does not modify the original document. `$.html` prints the original document and not the modified one.

```
    $ = cheerio.load(data);
    $("img").each(function() {
        var old_src=$(this).attr("src");
        var new_src = "/my_cached_image?url=" + encodeURIComponent(old_src);        
        $(this).prop("src", new_src);
    });
    modified_data = $.html();
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have a very small error,
"src" in an img it's an attribute and not a property.

So this code will work:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var data = "<img src='yahoo.com'/>"
$ = cheerio.load(data);
$("img").each(function() {
        var old_src=$(this).attr("src");
        var new_src = "/my_cached_image?url=" + encodeURIComponent(old_src);
        console.log(new_src);
        $(this).attr("src", new_src);            
});

console.log($.html());
```

output is

```
<img src="/my_cached_image?url=yahoo.com">
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.attr('src', new_src)`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#attr-name-value-) instead of `.prop()`.