# How to replace all blob image with image file src using nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, image, express

On submitting form from RTE which takes all images as blob, I need to replace all the `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...paps/== >`
tag with sth like `<img src="../assets/imgs/abc.png" >`

I got all the images in the array but how to replace the same while pushing it in array, any module of nodejs which can help ?

```
 var str = req.body.desc; 
    console.log(str);
    var m,
    srcList = [],
    rex = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\>/g;
    while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
      // upload the base 64 to file and get the new path
      var new_path = "....";
     srcList.push(new_path);
     }
    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(srcList);
```

Comment: where does the filename come from?

Comment: @dandavis while saving it can be given random name and replacing the base64 with the path of the file stored,

Comment: could do it easy with FS.writeFileSync or make it better/complicated and use writeFile to make the path have the bits by the time it's served.

Comment: didn't get it ? how to implement this ?

Comment: @dandavis thanks for help .. however
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36012245/1391499 this worked for me